# Double Integral from Polar to Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I know that when converting a double integral from Cartesian to Polar Coordinates, the Jacobian is equal to r and so we get $\iint dxdy$ $=$ $\iint rdrd\theta$. But what if I wanted to go from Polar to Cartesian Coordinates? What would the Jacobian be?

Answer (score 4):

Use $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan\dfrac{y}{x}$, then obtain
$$\left|\begin{array}{rr}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y} \\\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}  \end{array}\right|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\color{blue}{\dfrac1r}$$

Comment: (+1).  OP, please note that for *any* valid coordinate transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, if the Jacobian is $J$, the Jacobian of the inverse transformation is $\frac{1}{J}$.